# How to efficiently update models with references(dropdownList )with asp mvc and nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, updatemodel

I started to develop a web application (application portfolio) with nhibernate and asp mvc2.

I have some difficulties to properly change the category of an application.
Here are my models:

```
 public class Application 
 {
    public virtual int  Application_ID{ get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
 }
 public class Category : ILookupItem
 {
    public virtual int Category_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get;  set; }
 }
```

My viewModel:

```
public class ApplicationEditModel
{
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
}
```

My Form:

```
<% Html.BeginForm(new {id= Model.Application.Application_ID }); %>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><%=Html.LabelFor(x => x.Application.Application_ID)%></td>
    <td><%=Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Application.Application_ID) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%=Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Application.Name) %></td>
    <td><%=Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Application.Name) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%=Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Application.Category) %></td>
<td><%=Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Application.Category.Category_ID,Model.Categories,"Select a category") %></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

My controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {   
        Application app =  _service.FindById(id);
        TryUpdateModel<Application>(app, "Application");
        _service.CommitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I can assign a new category, but if I change to a different category I get the following message:

> identifier of an instance of Core.Model.Category was altered from 2 to 3

This seems to be because the defaultmodelbinder is updating the key of the assigned category instead of assigning a new category with new new key.

What is the correct way to update an entity with all its references?
I could maybe use a custom view model, bind it in the controller, and then map it to my domain model. But I fear that it will give me too much work (at the end I will have around 100 properties,30 references and 5-6 lists in my application model).
Could Automapper be useful in this case to update an existing domain model?
How are you handling this kind of update?

Comment: Have you found solution to this problem. I am having the exact same problem. I am using MVC3

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to use the same model as both view and domain model unless you have a very simple application. Another reason to have a separate domain model is that it is not very user friendly to show a huge form for all of the 100 properties. You can better show the user different forms for different tasks. When you do that, you end up with different viewmodels for one domain entity anyway.

Comment: Ok, I can easily split my model into several view models, but how do you update your model then? Manually by copying to properties of the updated view model to the domain model?  
How do you handle updates in a list? by looping though the list and comparing the items?

Comment: Yes indeed. Most of the time I call a method in the domain model that change the properties. The method names are an important part of the domain model because the identify how the domain is used.